# Wait until an element has a value - not just exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of dynamic dropdown menus which are populated using JQuery/Javascript via a javascript array. As you select different parent dropdown values the children change. Fairly basic stuff.

We have an issue where a another javascript function needs to use a child dropdownlist value in order to process.

As the scripts run asyncronously there are situations where the value is not populated by the time the second script needs the value.

I was hoping to use setTimeout to 'wait' for the value to be set by the first script before continuing the second script.

I lifted the code below from another thread but it only ever seems to wait 'once', it never waits 50ms and then wait again if the condition is not set.

```
            var waitForEl = function(selector, callback) {
                if (($('#'+selector).val())) {
                    console.log('good to go');
                    callback();
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        console.log('paused for thought');
                        waitForEl(selector,callback);
                    },50);
                }
            };

            $('[id^="currentcontainersizeid"]').each(function() {
                thisId = $(this).attr('id').replace(/^\D+/g, "")
                if (($('#currentcontainersizeid'+thisId).length > 0) && ($('#currentcontainersizeid'+thisId).val())) {
                    waitForEl('containersizeid'+thisId, function() {
                        console.log('FIRE TRIGGER');
                        $('#containersizeid'+thisId).trigger('change');
                    });
                }
            });
```

I am not sure whether it is my test that is wrong or the timeout logic. Should I be checking whether the element is 'selected' rather than has a 'val'. If so how would I do that?
Does the code above look correct to achive what I want?

Thoughts/help appreciated.

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. You need to fix it in another way. Can you post a [mcve] of the current situation and then we can see if we can fix the issue without a wait. Click edit then `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: *by the time the second script needs the value* - then this second script is not running at the correct time.  Either change it from "auto-run" to "user-run" (manually-run) by adding a button that the user clicks when they've selected what they want or raise an event from the code that sets the value and listen for that.

Comment: Maybe it's not "waiting" because `.val()` is returning truthy - ie your default `<option>` has a `value=`

Comment: Unfortunatly, we cannot make it user run event. It is a 'modify' form being populated by existing values. There is already a click event on the dropdown that performs what we need but we also need to 'set' the form correctly from the existing values - hence my issue. Unfortunatly this only effects some browsers on some machines and even then it only 'breaks' ocassionally because it is a timing issue. Sometimes the timng is on our side, ocassionally not. I will be looking at this further to sort out the bigger issue but right now I am implementing a dirty 'fix' to get things working.

Comment: You already have a user-event "click event performs what we need".  How does it get "populated by existing values [implied: on load]"?

Comment: Your waitForEl code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/vf0j3k7b/1/ - if it's hitting "good to go" on first call, then there's something wrong with the `if($(selector)...` line/check.

Comment: Try changing the *global* variable `thisId` to `let thisId = $(this).attr('id').replace(/^\D+/g, "")` so that it's not changed when it triggers after "fire trigger"

Comment: Can you detail what **does** happen?  does it call the waitForEl?  Does it always go into "good to go" immediately?  Do you get "fire trigger" but the event is not triggered?  Please make a complete snippet (see [mcve]) that demonstrates the issue (with multiple dropdowns so your `.each` has more than one entry).

Comment: freedomn-m - thanks for the sanity check on the code - much appreciated. I will get a reproducable together.